# What is the `bmiColors` member in the `BITMAPINFO` structure?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, gdi

```
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFO {
  BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader;
  RGBQUAD          bmiColors[1];
} BITMAPINFO, *PBITMAPINFO;
```

I never really understood what the values in the `bmiColors` array do. I usually 0-fill it, but putting in any arbitrary value doesn't affect my application at all.

The MSDN documentation is also ambiguous on what that member does, when I simply manipulate the pixels in the `COLORREF` array allocated by `CreateDIBSection`, and then `bitblt`.

What is `bmiColors`?

Comment: It lets you define the palette for an indexed bitmap (i.e. 256 colors or fewer).

Comment: @JonathanPotter So it's not of use when I do not use an indexed bitmap?

Comment: If you're not using 256 colours or less you can leave it out completely and just use a BITMAPINFOHEADER.

Comment: `bmiColors` is not used just for indexed bitmaps. 16bit and 32bit bitmaps use it if they are using bitfield compression: "*If the biCompression member of the BITMAPINFOHEADER is BI_BITFIELDS, **the bmiColors member contains three DWORD color masks that specify the red, green, and blue components, respectively, of each pixel**. Each (D)WORD in the bitmap array represents a single pixel*."